# Re-using destination instances in a collection property with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have an edit model and an EF entity, and I want to use AutoMapper to update the entity with data from the edit model. This works very well:

```
// The classes involved
public class FooEditModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FooProp { get; set; }
}

public class FooEntity {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FooProp { get; set; }
}

// Mapper configuration
cfg.CreateMap<FooEditModel, FooEntity>();

// Actual usage
var entity = _dbContext.Foos
    .Where(e => e.Id == id) // id is a route param
    .Single();
_mapper.Map(editModel, entity); // editModel is populated by model binding
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now, `entity` has been updated with the value of `FooProp` from `editModel`. All is well.

However, when I add a collection of a different type, it doesn't work as well as I'd like anymore

```
// classes
pulic class FooEditModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<BarEditModel> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class BarEditModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string BarProp { get; set; }
}

public class FooEntity {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IReadOnlyCollection<BarEntity> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class BarEntity {
    public string BarProp { get; set; }
}

// mapper config
cfg.CreateMap<FooEditModel, FooEntity>();
cfg.CreateMap<BarEditModel, BarEntity>();

// usage
var entity = _dbContext.Foos
    .Include(f => f.Bars)
    .Where(f => f.id == id)
    .Single();

_mapper.Map(editModel, entity);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Now, instead of updating the `FooEntity` as well as all related `BarEntity`s, it gives me an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'BarEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

How do I configure AutoMapper so that the mapper will re-use the objects in the existing collection, rather than try to replace them?

Comment: Take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thomas

You should understand what is going on under the hood. AutoMapper is a simple tool, which uses reflection to avoid line by line property rewriting. Nevertheless, it is creating new objects from time to time (as in your example with collections) Without collections the mapper is not creating anything - it is simply rewriting properties. If you add collections, he is handling this by creating new collections to map new collections from editModel.

This creates a situation where on DataContext, you have instantiated objects of type Bar and mapper is creating a new one which leads to conflict.

As Ivan Stoev stated, you can use Automapper.Collection to handle such situation (i never used it though, but it probably address this problem)

Comment: AutoMapper.Collection does indeed solve this problem - thanks (both to you and Ivan)! I had some trouble getting it to work at first, but that turned out to be mostly because it poses requirements on configuration that were hard to fulfill while also using AutoMapper.Attributes - so I ditched the latter, and now it's working.